# Unable to install packages due to run-hooks error

Tags: package, hooks, package-repositories, install

I'm getting a strange error when installing packages using package-install.
I haven't really updated anything in my configs but package installation suddenly stopped working. Any pointers or suggestions would be grateful.

- Here's the message buffer. As you can see, after *Scrapping files for loaddefs* there's a sudden error that completely stops package installation.

```
Packages to install: 2 (ox-jekyll-md-20211222.1718 org-modern-20240102.329).  Proceed? (y or n) y
Operation [ Install 2 ] started
File mode specification error: (void-function nil)
Saving file /home/dks/.emacs.d/personal/custom.el...
Wrote /tmp/.!home!dks!.emacs.d!personal!custom.el.~undo-tree~
Wrote /home/dks/.emacs.d/personal/custom.el
Wrote /tmp/.!home!dks!.emacs.d!personal!custom.el.~undo-tree~
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Parsing tar file...done
Extracting...done
  INFO     Scraping files for loaddefs... 
run-hooks: Symbol’s function definition is void: nil
Reverting buffer ‘personal’
```

- And this is the debug trace.
  [image: stacktrace]

Comment: Check each of the hook variables listed in that `run-hooks` frame of the backtrace, and see if any of them contain an explicit `nil` value.  Presumably one of them does, and finding out which one is the culprit would help you to then try to discover what has caused that to happen.

Comment: @phils Thank you for this tip i was able to fix it after some looking! It turns out there was a problem with emacs-lisp-mode-hook where i added a function the incorrect way. Lesson learned, don't add to hooks like `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (flycheck-mode -1))`